# Why does performing DFS with this code result in duplicate leaves?

Tags: javascript, typescript, algorithm, binary-search-tree, depth-first-search

I am writing an algorithm that discerns whether two trees have the same leaves.

[image: These have the same leaf numbers in the same order so this returns true]

These have the same leaf numbers in the same order so this returns true.

This is the code I wrote:

```
function leafSimilar(root1: TreeNode | null, root2: TreeNode | null): boolean {

    console.log(DFS(root1))

    const leavesRoot1 = DFS(root1);
    const leavesRoot2 = DFS(root2);

    for (let i = 0; i < Math.max(leavesRoot1.length, leavesRoot2.length); i += 1) {
        if (leavesRoot1[i] !== leavesRoot2[i]) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
};

function DFS(root, leaves = [] ) {

    if(!root) return leaves; 

    if (!root.left && !root.right) {
        leaves.push(root.val);
        return leaves;
    }

    // return DFS(root.left).concat(DFS(root.right)); // this is the correct answer

    return DFS(root.left, leaves).concat(DFS(root.right, leaves)); // why doesn't this work?
}
```

The last line in the code is what i initially thought, but it is wrong.

I couldn't draw it in my mind so I logged them as seen in the second line.

It logs:

```
[
  6, 7, 4, 
  6, 7, 4, 
  6, 7, 4, 
  6, 7, 4, 9, 8,
  6, 7, 4, 9, 8
]
```

After 2 hours, I cannot figure out why this is.

I would think it should be at least something similar to this:

```
[6, 
 6, 7, 
 6, 7, 4, 
 6, 7, 4, 9,
 6, 7, 4, 9, 8,
]
```

or just

```
[6,7,4,9,8]
```

which is the correct one.

Would someone be able to explain to me why?

The `DFS` function takes `leaves` array argument from the previous call.

This means that it should receive `leaves` from the node above, not below, so there shouldn't be a repeat pattern in the `leaves` array because it is empty.

The DFS is in preorder according to the code I wrote, so the left-most nodes are evaluated first.

Please help me understand.

Comment: Why didn't you just debug it? Consider the case where you're at the node with value 1. If you use `DFS(root.left, leaves)` then you run into `if (!root.left && !root.right)` and then return *all leaves so far* because that's what you passed as `leaves`. Instead of the leaves reachable from 1.

Comment: @VLAZ Thanks. I get that part, but the part I don't get is this. When we are at value 1, isn't leaves = [] ? I don't get how it is [6,7,4] at that moment. We evaluate the left nodes first, but that shouldn't influence the right nodes. In other words, at the VERY root(val: 3), how does the right nodes have access to what was returned from the left nodes?([6,7,4])

Comment: "*when we are at value 1, isn't leaves = []*" you've traversed depth first, left to right, so when you reach 1 you've visited 3 - 4 - 5- 2 - 7 - 4 (taking the left tree as an example) before reaching it. If you pass *the same* array of leaves around, then you have one array of leaves. It's not empty because it's already been modified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach would work if you would have done it this way:

```
    DFS(root.left, leaves);
    DFS(root.right, leaves);
    return leaves;
```

Here we ignore the array *returned* by `DFS`. Realise that when the first recursive call returns, `leaves` has some values from the left subtree. The second recursive call *extends* this array with more values. The right thing to do is to return `leaves` after that second population has happened.

Be aware that `DFS` returns a reference to the `values` array, so in essence each call returns the *same* reference. If you do `values.concatenate(values)` it is clear you duplicate values, but that is exactly what you are doing with:

```
DFS(root.left, leaves).concat(DFS(root.right, leaves));
```

It just is a bit more obscure... because `values` is getting populated in both recursive calls. But that is quite irrelevant to explain the problem. The key understanding is that both recursive calls return a reference to the same array.

To avoid such problems, it is good practice to *never* have a function return the reference to an object that was also passed as argument, and which it mutates. It is better to choose between these two patterns:

- Have the function take the object (array in this case) as argument, but return undefined. This way the caller is made more aware that their argument has been mutated.
- Have the function *not* take the object as argument, but have it construct one from scratch, which it then can return to the caller. In this pattern each call of the function returns a distinct object reference.

Mixing these two patterns can easily lead to the problems you have encountered.  In this actual algorithm, I have a clear preference for the second pattern, and then there shouldn't be a `values` argument. So:

```
function DFS(root) {
    if (!root) return []; 
    if (!root.left && !root.right) return [root.val];
    return DFS(root.left).concat(DFS(root.right));
}
```

The downside is that a lot of little arrays are created here, and concatenating all of them can be costly.

More elegant is to make use of a generator function. You get the best of both worlds: you avoid creating little arrays from scratch each time, and you avoid passing an array as argument that mutates.

```
function leafSimilar(root1, root2) {
    const leavesRoot1 = [...DFS(root1)]; // consume the iterator
    const leavesRoot2 = [...DFS(root2)];

    for (let i = 0; i < Math.max(leavesRoot1.length, leavesRoot2.length); i += 1) {
        if (leavesRoot1[i] !== leavesRoot2[i]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
};

function* DFS(root) {
    if (!root) return; 
    if (!root.left && !root.right) yield root.val;
    yield* DFS(root.left);
    yield* DFS(root.right);
}
```